# Discover an object's type inside a template

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a more elegant way of discovering the type of a templete parameter than using dynamic_cast. Ex

```
template< typename TypeA, typename TypeB >
bool foo( TypeA* x, TypeB* y )

if( dynamic_cast< WantedType* >( x ) != NULL ) // More ellegant way of doing this
   // found specific type, setting its stuff
```

Maybe a specialization `template< WantedType TypeA, ... >` but this would result in duplicated code to do the same.

Comment: Do you want it at runtime or compile time?

Comment: Asking for the type within a template is inelegant period, simply because it's a sign of a flawed design.  Why code generically if the type matters? Either have generic code that's type agnostic, or write your code for a type.

Comment: @user1161318 not so much, there's a reason for specialized templates. Maybe we have a thousand methods call, but just one plus specific for a class, why not? should I put it in the base class and all others will carry will PAYload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::is_same<A,B>::value` tells you if A and B are the same type or not.

However the odds are you are making a mistake.

`dynamic_cast` is for checking the runtime type of an instance, which is not the same thing as the compile time type of the same variable in many contexts.

Comment: I see, if typename is a base class, is_same would take base, not the in memory value. So for a specialization held in a base pointer is_same will always return false.

Comment: Your use of words is off.  `is_same` operates on types not values is the important part.  If you want to know if type `X` is a child of type `Y` there are similar traits classes that give you that answer.  If your question is about instances not types, `dynamic_cast` is reasonable.  As is custom `virtual` methods if you have only a few types to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option, which might be more inline with your original train of thought ( not saying it's the best way of doing it ):

Try using the method `typeid()`,   ( `#include <typeinfo>` ).

Given your code, you could do

```
if ( typeid( x ).name() == typeid( wantedType ).name() ) { ...
```

with wantedType being `int`, `char` or whatever.

**EDIT**

Have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf39xec%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Seems the argument of `typeid` can be any object.

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe a specialization template< WantedType TypeA, ... >

Either overloading or specialisation is definitely the way to go. Everything else is hacky and makes the code more complex.

> but this would result in duplicated code to do the same.

Ideally it shouldn’t. If you’ve properly decomposed your function then there’s only minimal code duplication (= the function headers).

Answer (score 1):

You could use template specialization for compile time checks:

```
template <typename A>
class IsClassWantedType 
{
  public:
    static const bool value = false;
}

template <>
class IsClassWantedType <WantedType>
{
  public:
    static const bool value = true;
}

template< typename TypeA, typename TypeB >
bool foo( TypeA* x, TypeB* y )
{

  if( IsClassWantedType<TypeA>::value == true )
  {
    //Do Stuff
  }

}
```

Just note that there's no polymorphism here... It won't check for derived types.
For derived types you'd have to use more complicated **[SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)** tricks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typeid(t).name()` to do just that.

example code:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;



template <class T>
string toString(const T& t)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << t;

    cout<<"The Datatype is a "<< typeid(t).name()  <<" \n";

    return ss.str();
}



int main(void)
{

    string str;

    char c=123;
    str=toString(c );

    int i=1234;
    str=toString(i );

    double d=1234;
    str=toString(d );



  cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```

output:

```
The Datatype is a char
The Datatype is a int
The Datatype is a double
```